# Use functions from a class in another class without extending?

Tags: php, oop, pdo, attributes, extend

I have multiple classes, in this case `Core` and `User`. At this moment `User` is an extension of `Core`. In `Core`, I have my main functions that are required in multiple classes, for example a database connection through PDO. I use a `__construct` function to build the database connection, no problems with that.

However, in my `User` class, I want to pass values to multiple attributes through `__construct`. For example a Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password and a few other attributes.

When doing this, I get a warning from Netbeans that the parent constructor should be used, and a lot of vague errors, I don't ask you to fix these errors.

I would like to know if there is a way for me to use the database connection function from `Core` in `User` without making the extension. I hope it is more clear with a little bit of background information!

Below both classes, only showing the parts related to the question:

```
abstract class Core implements ICore {

private $_dbcon;


public function __construct($_database){
    $this->_dbcon = $_database;
}

public function _connectDB(){
    return $this->_dbcon;
}

class User extends Core implements IUser {

public $_username;
private $_password;
protected $_email;
protected $_adres;
protected $_phone;
protected $_contactperson;
protected $_company;
protected $_kvk;

public function __construct($_username, $_password, $_email, $_adres, $_phone, $_contactperson, $_company, $_kvk){
    $this->_username = $_username;
    $this->_password = $_password;
    $this->_email = $_email;
    $this->_adres = $_adres;
    $this->_phone = $_phone;
    $this->_contactperson = $_contactperson;
    $this->_company = $_company;
    $this->_kvk = $_kvk;
}
```

Comment: Yes - just declare an instance of core in user.

Comment: Thanks! going to look into dependency injection to only have to declare it once, but thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the parent constructor.

```
class User extends Core
{
    public function __construct($db, $username, ...)
    {
        parent::__construct($db);

        $this->_username = $_username;
        ...          
    }
}
```

But in your case I would think about a better overall design. Read about [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). In this way you'd only have one DB connection and use that connection in other classes.

```
class User
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(Db $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah great, thank you! Will definitely look into dependency injection, guess that would be way more usefull on a larger scale instead of the first method